# How to retrieve current week data in MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve current week data from MySql.

For example : **Previous Sunday to Saturday from current day**.

How can i do that? Please help me.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your date field must of datetime type

and sql query will be like :

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE yearweek(DATE(field_name), 1) = yearweek(curdate(), 1)
```

Comment: the 2nd parameter is for setting the weekstart from monday so if its needed to be from sunday to sunday then no need to pass 2nd param. +1 for this answer !!

Comment: what if the field is date and not datetime?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT DATE(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 0) AS StartWeek,
DATE(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 5) AS EndWeek
```